# AttributeError when importing random

Tags: python, random, import, attributeerror

I'm having some issues importing random into my python program. I've read through other threads on this topic and for others, it seemed to stem from the file being named random.py.

My file is not named random.py. I have used print(random.**file**) to see where it is importing from, and it seems to be importing from C:\Python27\lib\random.pyc

I have tried moving that file out of the folder and it still does not work.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Projects/Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    r1 = random.randomint(20,400)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randomint'
```

I have also tested in both powershell and the interpreter.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import random
import getpass

r1 = random.randomint(20,400)
r2 = random.randomint(20,400)
p = getpass.getpass(prompt='Please enter the correct value: %d * %d: ' %(r1,r2))

if p == (r1*r2):
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "Incorrect"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Edit: I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Correct name of the function is `random.randint` not `random.randomint`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>> import random
>> random.randint(20,400)
76
```

`AttributeError` raise cause of error in function spelling. You should use `randint` instead of `randomint`.

Answer (score 0):

Ha I had this too.. I wrote a python file to generate random numbers... but called it random.py so it did not work!... once I renamed it AND deleted random.pyc it worked fine